# How do I get this user prompt to accept the type of input I want?

Tags: java

In this line I need to input the following "MacBook Pro" however it brings up and error. This is the code in question.

```
 System.out.print("What brand of computer do you wish to purchase? "); // user prompt
    model = scanner.next(); // read input here as a string
```

This is the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "pro"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at p2code.Computer.main(Computer.java:22)
```

Declaration added for clarification

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);   // Declare a Scanner object here to be used for input
    String input;
    String brand;
    String model;
```

Lines 20-23 below

```
    System.out.print("Enter the cost of the computer: "); //user prompt
        input=scanner.next(); //reads input as string 
        price = Double.parseDouble(input); // converts string to double and stores in price variable
    totalTax = (price * kTax);
```

Comment: Can you post the declaration part of the code. Seems like model is declared with Double

Comment: as the exception refers to line 22 in your code (Computer.java:22) - > show us that line plus a few before and after :-)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use nextLine() to input the "Macbook Pro".
next() only takes a single word as input.
So pro is left and error is thrown.